# How to reset the scale in QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

How can I reset the scale of a Graphics View regardless of any previous scale that was applied? Using `scale()` multiplies the scale I give it to the previous one:

```
ui->graphicsView->scale(0.1, 0.1);
ui->graphicsView->scale(2, 2);
// the scale factor is (0.2,0.2) instead of (2,2)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`QGraphicsView::resetMatrix()` resets the matrix, and calling it before applying the scale works:

```
view->scale(0.1, 0.1);
view->resetMatrix();
view->scale(2, 2);
// the scale factor is (2,2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Something to added:

QGraphicsView::resetMatrix() is equal to QGraphicsView::resetTransform(), which can see from source code:

```
void QGraphicsView::resetMatrix()
{
    resetTransform();
}
```

Comment: Yes, now you have to use resetTransform() since resetMatrix() has been deprecated.